# Joining tables by specific column using Doctrine

Tags: php, mysql, doctrine, symfony-1.4, left-join

I am trying to get a single record for one table by checking for a variable that is in two associated tables.

For instance my tables are

```
user:
id   |  name 
3781 |  Foo Manchu

user_programs:
id    | user_id |  page_id
4150  | 3781    |  16974

Page
id     |  title   |   section_id
16974  |  Dudes   |   3
```

So I need to query and return the Users who have a section_id of 3

Users are associated to the user_program table which are assocaited to specific pages through page_id.

This is what I have which is not returning anything:

```
if($section_id == 3) {
      $q = $this->createQuery('u');
      $q->leftJoin('u.user_programs up');
      $q->leftJoin('up.Page p');
      $q->where('u.published=1 AND u.is_preview = 0 AND u.featured=1 AND fp.deleted_at IS NULL');

      $q->addWhere('p.section_id=?', $section_id);
      $q->orderBy('RAND()')->limit(1);
```

I can succesfully return the u query without doing the join, but I need to limit the query to only return users with a section_id on the associated page of 3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the schema is correct, then a User should have a Pages (or something like that) relation. You can write the query like this:

```
$query = $this->createQuery('u')
  ->innerJoin('u.Pages p')
  ->andWhere('u.published = ?', 1)
  ->andWhere('u.is_preview = ?', 0)
  ->andWhere('u.featured = ?', 1)
  ->addWhere('p.section_id = ?', $section_id)
  ->limit(1)
;
```

I removed the `fp.deleted_at` part as it makes no sense when using  `SoftDelete` (I presume you use that) and the `fp` alias was not in the original query anyway.